# Ecto migration alter table ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matches

Tags: erlang, elixir, database-migration, ecto

While running `mix ecto.migrate` I was bumping into this issue

```
10:53:59.187 [info] == Running 
20201005163129 Universe.Repo.Migrations.UpdatePlanetsTable.change/0 forward
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matches
```

With the following migration

```
  alter table(:planet) do
    add :solar_system, :string
    modify :name, null: false
  end
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was not giving `modify` the second argument for the
type of the field and instead only the options.

```
  alter table(:planet) do
    add :solar_system, :string
    modify :name, :string, null: false
  end
```

Always look up the correct prototype when

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matches
```

Also would be nice to have the name of the function/macro in the error.

Comment: Nice job debugging.  Yeah, any time you're in macro-land, the errors can get really hard to interpret.  With migrations, I would recommend testing them early and often so you can laser in on the problematic lines as quickly as possible.